# Promise after forEach loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, es6-promise

I am new to promises and trying to figure out for quite a long time now how to get proper results after the usage of a async network call with which I receive data.

I receive my balance from a exchange and loop through several parameters. When this is finished the `holdings` should be returned.

However, I still have to fight the async behaviour. When I run the code without the commented code, the result is `[]`. If I set a artificial setTimeout, then the returned array `holdings` is visible properly.

Can someone tell me please where my mistake lays? I tried to read through docs of mdn and similar problems here on stackoverflow but I am nonetheless stuck.

Thank you guys very much,

Tobias

```
const bittrex = require('node.bittrex.api');
const {key, secret} = require('./key')

let getBalance = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let holdings = [];
  bittrex.getbalances( function( data, err ) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    data.result.forEach(coin => {
      if (coin.Balance !== 0) {
        let market = `BTC-${coin.Currency}`;
        if(coin.Currency === 'BTC') market = `USDT-BTC`;
        bittrex.getticker( { market : market}, function( ticker, err ) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          holdings.push({
            Coin: coin.Currency,
            Balance: coin.Balance,
            Last: ticker.result.Last
          });
        })
      }
    });
  });
  resolve(holdings);
})

getBalance
// .then((holdings) =>{
//   return new Promise((resolve, reject)  => {
//     setTimeout(() => {
//       resolve(holdings);
//     }, 10000)
//   })
// })
  .then((holdings) => {
        console.log(holdings);
  })
```

Comment: `getticker()` is also asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're resolving your promise instantaneously but the data is not here yet, as it is happened asynchronously during the callback. Your promise should be resolved after every callback.

What you should do is create a promise for each of the request and then resolve your function with a Promise.all

```
const bittrex = require('node.bittrex.api');
const {key, secret} = require('./key')
let getBalance = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let holdings = [];
  bittrex.getbalances( function( data, err ) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    const promises = data.result.map(coin => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (coin.Balance !== 0) {
        let market = `BTC-${coin.Currency}`;
        if(coin.Currency === 'BTC') market = `USDT-BTC`;
        bittrex.getticker( { market : market}, function( ticker, err ) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve({
            Coin: coin.Currency,
            Balance: coin.Balance,
            Last: ticker.result.Last
          });
        })
      }
    });

    resolve(Promise.all(promises));
  });
});
```

Your getBalance promise will be resolved when all of your promise are resolved. Be cautious though, if one of your promise is rejected, then the whole promise will be rejected.

If it's properly resolved, then the value will be an array of each value of the promises.

Comment: Thank you for your answer with which I got a better understanding of promises.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
`


I think I still have a problem with missing a return statement though I tried to implement your version.


Any idea where?

Comment: Got it. I haven't seen the .map function, instead tried it with forEach...
Thank you 2 so much for answering me.
Feels good to grasp the idea :-)
Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Axnyff for the explanation. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm assuming `bittrex.getticker` is async, you should instead just wrap each call into a promise and not try to combine them into one manually.

Here's a loose concept.

```
function getTicker(...) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        bittrex.getticker(..., function(ticker, error) {
            if (error) { reject(error); }
            else { resolve(ticker); }
        });
    });
}

var lotsOfPromises = data.result.map(function(coin) {
    return getTicker(...).then(function(ticker) {
        return { yourOutputdata }
    });
});

Promise.all(lotsOfPromises);
```